# Copy one column from one table to another in same database with respect to id phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables;event and payment

I want to copy data from column `amount` of table `Payment` TO column `paid` of table `Event` where `Event.eid=Paymenet.event_id`

Kindly help if any one knows this.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do update

```
UPDATE  event a 
   JOIN payment b ON a.eid = b.event_id  
   SET a.paid = b.payment
```

Comment: I have different rows in payments table where event id is same but amount is different. Now I want to apply query in which amount of same event id in payments table gets added(sum up) and insert that added amount to Paid column in events table where payment.eventid=event.eventid. @zaynulabadintuhin